# Loop multiple matrices?

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I have a bunch of matrices for different fruits. I have an equation multiplying certain part of the matrix together as well as with another matrix (i.e. master_bwf). I need to apply this same formula to the different fruit matrices which are set out in exactly the same way. Essentially, I just need to change the matrix in *italics* over and over again and print the value.

Any suggestions, would a loop work?

```
apple_national_prodwf <- (sum(fbs_apple[1:35, "fbs.P_tonne"] *
                              master_bwf [1:35, 1])) -
                         (fbs_apple[36, "fbs.FE_tonne"] *
                          mean(master_bwf[1:35, 1]))
```

Comment: Please give an small example with input and corresponding output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you stick your fruit matrices into a list `fruit_list` then you could do something like:

```
mean_master_bwf <- mean(master_bwf [1:35,1])
fruit_national_prodwf <- sapply(fruit_list, function(fbs) 
     (sum(fbs[1:35, "fbs.P_tonne"] * master_bwf [1:35,1])) - 
     (fbs[36, "fbs.FE_tonne"] * mean_master_bwf))
```

Note also that you needn't recompute the mean of the master_bws in each iteration as it references the same column each time.

**Update following OP's comment**:

Take the column means of the master_bwf table to get a vector of means per fruit:

```
mean_master_bwf <- colMeans(master_bwf)
```

Now assuming the columns in master_bwf are in the same order as the fruit matrices, you could do:

```
fruit_national_prodwf <- sapply(1:NROW(fruit_list), 
    function(i) (sum(fruit_list[[i]][1:35, "fbs.P_tonne"] * master_bwf [1:35, i])) - 
                (fruit_list[[i]][36, "fbs.FE_tonne"] * mean_master_bwf[i]))
```

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect! One thing I forgot to mention is that for the master_bwf matrix I actually need to change the column that its is needed to multiply. So for this example the wf of apples is in column 1 i.e. [1:35,1], for the next matrix (e.g. oranges), I would need to do the same thing but multiply by columnn 2 (i.e. 1:35, 2) of the master_bwf matrix.  Would I need to put an 'i' somewhere?